# my apps are showing ads perfectly but there isnt any clicks/impressions/revenue on admob app page

Tags: android, google-play, admob, ads

My apps are showing ads perfectly but there isnt any action on admob app page. I checked id, everything is true. i can see how many minute playing on my page. but still 0 earning.. its same about 5 days

The problem is we have 0 Requests and 0 impression. But our app is showing ads without any problem and We have User metrics. So someone is playing and watching ads but we cant earn anything. Our app-ads.txt is active.

Answer (score 0):

1st thing, make sure that your app id and ads unit id are correct? if everything is correct then wait a little bit longer, especially if this is your first app on AdMob, analytic data tend to be late with first app.

side note: never click on your ads

Comment: i am sure i dont have any wrong thing, i checked to much.

its been 6days... and its not my first app. i am still earning money 6 apps.

Comment: Was this helpful? Did you manage to solve this?